# add values of multiple input boxes in Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, forms, codeigniter, jquery

i am working in a code igniter. i have a form which contain three input boxes in a row . ..i put them in a for loop which is less then five ..so now my form has five rows with three input boxes in a row .. now what i am doing write now i am adding the values of two input boxes and displaying in 3rd input box .. now what i want to do is when   every "total"(3rd input box) is filled .. then i am gonna add all the totals and then display all the totals in last box which i display at the bottom ..

here is my view

```
   <td><input type="text" id = "price_<?php echo $i ?>"
                      onkeyup='addition(<?php echo "$i"?>)'>

     </td>

<td> <input type="text" id = "quantity_<?php echo $i ?>" onkeyup='addition(<?php echo "$i"?>)'>
</td>

<td><input type="text"  id = "total_<?php echo $i ?>">
    </td>
```

```
 <?php echo form_input($subtotal)?></td> // here i want to display sum of all the totals
```

here is my javascript..this function is multiplying  the price and quantity ..i mean first and 2nd input box and then displaying in the 3rd box ..

```
  function addition (obj)
     {
var subtotal = 0;
var num1=parseInt($('#price_'+obj).val());
    var num2=parseInt($('#quantity_'+obj).val());
    var num4=parseInt($('#total_'+obj).val());

if ($('#price_'+obj).val() !='' && $('#quantity_'+obj).val() !='')
{
    var num3=num1*num2;
    $('#total_'+obj).val(num3);

} 

else
{
    $('#total_'+obj).val('');
 }


 }
```

i have uploaded the image also ..

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but what is your question?

Comment: @trung-heiu le .. the last box which you can see in blue highlighted colour in 3rd column ... i want to add all the total and then want to display in last blue higlighted input box ..... means the third column in which all the totals are coming .. ok then what i want is in the 6th input box of third column ..i want to display the sum of all the totals ..did you get it?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you use jQuery, I have modified your code a bit to use jQuery better. You can see the demo at [JsBIN](http://jsbin.com/emoziw/1/edit)

The idea is lock all "total" cell, when you update one "total" cell by calculating the result. Sum all "total" cell to the "grand-total" cell. I listen on the "keyup" event.

Comment: thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanks ..it works ... you rock man you rock ... thankkkkkkkk you very much

Answer (score 0):

Here is jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ner7M/2/

Code of interest:

```
var table = $('table');

// nth-child is 1-based, not 0
function totalColumn(table, idx) {
    var total = 0;
    var tds = $('table')
        .find('tr td:nth-child(' + idx + ') input')
        .each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    return total;
}

totalColumn(table, 3);
```